# Is their any possibility to fill area between two DataSet in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I need to fill in the area between the 2 charts. I tried to do this with FillFormatter, but it can fill only between the chart and the straight line. Is it possible to fill the area 2 charts as in the picture (bottom and top charts, thats describes max and min allowable values)? The grid must be visible with a white background [chart example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ml45u.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution

1. Disable standart grid:

   `getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
   getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);`
2. Add fill with FillFormatter as in this example:
   https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/remove_xindices/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/FilledLineActivity.java
3. Draw custom grid with [LimitLine](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v2.2.5/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/components/LimitLine.html):

   ```
    private void drawCustomGrid(XAxis xAxis, YAxis yAxis,
                               float xMax, float yMax,
                               int color, float width) {

       if (xAxis.getLimitLines().size() == 0) {

           for (int i = 10; i <= xMax; i += 10) {
               LimitLine limitLine = new LimitLine(i);
               limitLine.setLineWidth(width);
               limitLine.setLineColor(color);
               xAxis.addLimitLine(limitLine);
           }
       }

       if (yAxis.getLimitLines().size() == 0) {

           for (int j = 10; j <= yMax; j += 10) {
               LimitLine limitLine = new LimitLine(j);
               limitLine.setLineWidth(width);
               limitLine.setLineColor(color);
               yAxis.addLimitLine(limitLine);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the [FillFormatter](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v2.2.5/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/formatter/FillFormatter.html)  interface. You can apply it to a dataset using [mLineDataSet.setFillFormatter(mFillFormatter)](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v2.2.5/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineDataSet.html#setFillFormatter%28com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.FillFormatter%29).

Comment: FillFormatter returns float value, that mean the vertical (y-axis) position where the filled-line of the LineDataSet should end. I need to limit the fill area with 2 charts, described with DataSets

Answer (score 0):

Define a custom FillFormatter and LineChartRenderer. See the example here.

[Android - Fill the color between two lines using MPAndroidChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43342597/android-fill-area-between-two-lines-using-mpandroidchart/43452404#43452404)